# SharePoint Online how to add Links to Global Navigation Bar using PowerShell V5

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, global-navigation

I am trying to modify a PowerShell script to add Links to the SharePoint Online Global Navigation bar of my sites. I currently have a script which will add a "Header" to the Global Navigation Bar, but rather than add headers, I need to modify it to add “Links”.

Referencing the diagram below, I need the new link to appear as the example “Link1” Currently I can only add a header with the attached script which appears like the example “Hello1” below. Does anyone know how I can modify my script to make the Global Navigation item appear as a link?

[image: Settings View]

Script which adds a “Header”"

```
siteUrl = $_.Url
$siteTitle = $_.Title
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
 $context.Credentials = $credentials 
$context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10; 
$web = $context.Web 
$site = $context.Site 
$context.Load($web) 
$context.Load($site) 
$context.ExecuteQuery()  
$NavBar = $context.Web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar 
$NavigationNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
$NavigationNode.Title = $ItemName
$NavigationNode.Url = $ItemUrlPath
$NavigationNode.AsLastNode = $true           
$context.Load($NavBar.Add($NavigationNode)) 
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/AddPnPNavigationNode.md

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $_.Url
Add-PnPNavigationNode -Title $ItemName -Url <whatever you want> -Location TopNavigationBar -Header $ItemName
```